# Indicating library source file location to Visual Studio

Tags: visual-studio-2010, debugging, windows-phone-7, silverlight-toolkit

The February update to the Silverlight Toolkit seems to have introduced a bug into the `LongListSelector`. The [issue has been reported](http://silverlight.codeplex.com/workitem/8376) on CodePlex.

I run into this problem in my app because I have a page with a `LongListSelector` and in its `OnNavigatedTo` method I'm updating the selector's `ItemsSource`. This is necessary because the user can navigate to a settings page and toggle some settings which affect the data displayed in the `LongListSelector`. So, unless I update the `ItemsSource` each time, the changes are not displayed when the user navigates back to this page.

I'd like to dig into where exactly the `NullReferenceException` is being thrown within the `Balance` method, but cannot figure out how to tell Visual Studio (I'm using the express edition) where the toolkit source code is located. My project references the toolkit DLL from the GAC, but the actual source is located in another directory.

How can I tell Visual Studio where the source to step into is located?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add the toolkit source project to your solution and then reference the project, not the assembly in the GAC.

Answer (score 0):

What you can do is actually open the project in another visual studio (for the toolkit source code)... Then run the other project without debugging then attach to the process in the toolkit Visual studio.  (debug... attach to process) and that will allow you to set breakpoints and debug the process.

Comment: Unfortunately the attach to process option does not exist in the express edition (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/c6wf8e4z%28v=VS.100%29.aspx)